# Python unit-testing: Check if datestring is in the allowed format

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm unittesting my code and I want to make sure that the timestamps I get in are:

1. strings
2. In the format `YYYY<space>DDD:HH:MM:SS.sss<space>`  where `DDD` represents the day of the year.

What I've got is:

```
   def test_time(self, time_stamp)
       from datetime import datetime

       self.assertIsInstance(time_stamp,str, msg="%s not a string" %time_stamp)

       self.assertIsInstance(datetime.strptime(time_stamp, "%Y %j:%H:%M:%S.%f"), datetime.datetime)
```

The problem with this is that it the second assert is true for both `2014 031:09:59:59.862` (correct timestamp) and `2014 31:9:59:59.862` (incorrect timestamp).

How can I check that the timestamp has the correct format?

Comment: Use regexp or just try/except around `strptime`.  What's the problem with those approaches?

Comment: The problem is not that the `strptime` doesn't give me an datetime object. The problem is that the format I want requires me to makes sure that the day of the year is always 3 digits long, hours and minutes and seconds are always 2 digits long and so on

Comment: its day day of the year? or only day of the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow `strptime` by `strftime` to normalize the string to your desired format, and check if the original string equals the normalized string.

Comment: Thanks that helps! Just one question, I now have to do 
`d.strftime("%Y %j:%H:%M:%S.%f")[:21]` to get the right string. Is there a prettier way ?

Comment: @plover No, at least the docs don't seem to mention an option to get only millisecond precision.